# Complex malloc usage

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management

My program crashes always on the same allocation when I try to allocate memory for the `array_x`.

**In the code bellow if I uncommend the line `size = 10;` It works like charm. If I commend the line it crashes. Why?**

```
struct dt
{
    int *array_x;
    int b;

    void start(int size)
    {
        //size = 10;
        array_x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    }
};

void c_f()
{
    dt *d = (dt*)malloc(sizeof(dt)*100);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        d[i].start(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            d[i].array_x[j] = 1;
    }

    d = (dt*)realloc(d, sizeof(dt)*200);

    for(int i = 100; i < 200; i++)
    {
        d[i].start(i);//here it crashes
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            d[i].array_x[j] = 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            cout << d[i].array_x[j];
}
```

Comment: That's a pointer. Just because you can use it like an array doesn't make it one. I can use a vector like an array.

Comment: If I am forced to use C array, how to do this?

Comment: post ur code and we can advice u .

Comment: That was just part of the analogy (not that I'm saying it's a bad thing to use), but I can't tell what's wrong from the information given. An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would be helpful.

Comment: Show some real code. You can (in nearly all cases) use an array as a pointer and a pointer as an array, so sounds like what you want to do is possible. But without seeing the code, it's almost impossible to say if you are doing it right or not (if it's crashing, clearly you are not, but I mean if it's fundamentally broken or just a tiny bit wrong).

Comment: while _sizeof(int)_, or _sizeof(char)_ are commonly, and reasonably used, _sizeof(struct)_ is not because of its variable size, i.e. struct { int a; }A; will be a different size than say struct { int a; int b;}B;  So, using it in a malloc/calloc statement is not recommended.  On the other hand, sizeof(struct A) or sizeof(struct B) are useful.

Comment: I am trying to find a part wher this happens and acoid posting a 10 page code. @ryyker: what to use there then?

Comment: Just include the part of code that is relevant to the question you are asking.  For a start, include the structure definition, and how you are using it.

Comment: The definition of struct dt is incorrect.  It looks like a hybrid function.   Is your intent to prototype a function with a return type of struct dt?

Comment: Not sure what you mean...

Comment: Why dont you just pass 10 instead of 'i' in `d[i].start(i);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using `dt::start` inside the `for` loop, you are passing `0` to the function, leading:

```
(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
```

to be:

```
(int*)malloc(0);
```

Of course, accessing the returned pointer is undefined behavior.